# Can the cube of every perfect number be written as the sum of three cubes?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

I found an amazing conjecture: the cube of every perfect number can be written as the sum of three positive  cubes. The equation is
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=\sigma^3$$
where $\sigma$ is a perfect number
(well it holds good for the first three perfect numbers that is):

$${ 3 }^{ 3 }+{ 4 }^{ 3 }+{ 5 }^{ 3 }={ 6 }^{ 3 }$$
$${ 21 }^{ 3 }+{ 18 }^{ 3 }+{ 19 }^{ 3 }={ 28 }^{ 3 }$$
$${ 495 }^{ 3 }+{ 82 }^{ 3 }+{ 57 }^{ 3 }={ 496 }^{ 3 }$$

Is this what I am proposing that the cube of any perfect number can be expressed in terms of the sum of three positive cubes true?

If it is then can we prove it?

Comment: Where did you find this conjecture? Or did you just notice this for the first few cases?

Comment: None of $495$, $82$, and $57$ are prime.

Comment: See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=850020&sid=e8a8a5b303f3ccbe21ca5acd68fec620#p850020

Comment: We have a formula which gives the solution to this equation.  It should be associated with the perfect number.  And how to do it? We don't have a formula which gives all perfect numbers?  This is not properly the task. First it is necessary to have a formula describing all perfect numbers. To connect with the solution of the equation. And then to find out when decisions will be.

Comment: How far have you checked this? Note that here https://oeis.org/A023042 it looks like a large proportion of cubes are the sum of three cubes.

Comment: We know what all known perfect numbers look like: $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where $p$ and $2^{p}-1$ are primes. So it might be easier to try to prove for that case.

Comment: @individ It might be possible to use the definition of perfect number to prove it, without a closed formula. But it seems unlikely.

Comment: The even powers of $2^{2k}$ are congruent to $1$, $4$, $7$, $1$, $4$, and so on mod $9$. The corresponding $2^{2k+1}-1$ are congruent to $1$, $7$, $4$, $1$, and so on. The product is congruent to $1$, $1$, $1$, and so on. There is a famous conjecture that all numbers not of the form $9k\pm 4$ are a sum of three cubes. That would take care of even perfects.

Comment: so what is the end result

Comment: so what i am saying is true except that one of those numbers are primes

Comment: Are you looking for expressing the perfect number cubed as the sum of 3 **positive** cubes?

Comment: yes and can you prove it

Comment: but 8128 cube is a huge number and its very difficult to find cubes for it

Comment: @WillJagy: I took literally "sum of three cubes." OP probably intended sum of three non-negative cubes.

Comment: If the famous conjecture that all numbers not of the form 9k±4 are a sum of three cubes then 8128 cube can be expressed as the sum of three cubes

Comment: but is there any pattern in all these cubes

Comment: I have edited the question and please answer or give me a

Comment: A lead which I can follow in proving the question

Comment: surprised! nobody noticed this is a special case of [eulers conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) for cubes. it was disproved for 4th powers also. there is probably a clever computer program that can find counterexamples, at least that is how it was done for 4th powers. heres a [recent blog](http://bit-player.org/2014/four-fifths-a-fifth) on topic by by brian hayes

Comment: It doesn't work for 4

Answer (score 17):

As pointed out by E. Schmidt, the sequence [A023042](https://oeis.org/A023042) shows that a large percentage of cubes $N^3$ are a sum of three positive cubes. OEIS lists only $N<1770$, but we can extend that:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
N&\text{%}\\
\hline
2000&85.8\text{%}\\
4000&89.8\text{%}\\
6000&92.1\text{%}\\
8000&93.3\text{%}\\
10000&94.2\text{%}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

This means that $94.2\text{%}$ of all $N<10000$ have a solution to $a^3+b^3+c^3=N^3$ in positive integers. Note that $N=10000$ is still small. Extrapolating the table, it can be seen that the percentage may easily reach $99\text{%}$ if we go into the *millions*.

Thus, if we pick a random $N$ in the high end of the range, there is a *very good chance* that there is an $a,b,c$. For the next perfect number $N=8128$, it is just *mere statistics* that suggests $N^3$ will be the sum of three positive cubes, ***and not because it is perfect***. In fact, like $496$, it is in several ways,

$$2979^3 + 4005^3 + 7642^3 = 8128^3$$

$$2^6(102^3 + 673^3 + 2007^3) = 8128^3$$

$$2^9(197^3 + 198^3 + 1011^3) = 8128^3$$

And it was almost certain for the next perfect number which is in the millions,

$$2^{27}(3042^3 + 56979^3 + 45845^3) = 33550336^3$$

$$2^{30}(821^3 + 32590^3 + 8227^3) = 33550336^3$$

$$2^{36}(4543^3 + 6860^3 + 5104^3) = 33550336^3$$

Both can be expressed in many more ways than this, and I have only chosen a sample. For the cube of the next perfect number, or $137438691328^3$, chances are *even* greater that it is a sum of three positive cubes in *many* ways as well.

**Update:** Yes, it is:

$$2^{54}(425664^3 + 358719^3 + 275140^3)= 137438691328^3$$

$$2^{54}(432204^3 + 386604^3 + 177535^3)= 137438691328^3$$

---

**Note:** Jarek Wroblewski has calculated $a^3+b^3+c^3 = d^3$ with $\color{brown}{\text{co-prime}}$ $a,b,c$, and $d<1000000$ in his [website](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/eslp/tables.htm). Using his database and some help with *Mathematica* and *Excel*, I came up with the table above which counts all $N$, regardless of whether $a,b,c$ is co-prime or not.

**P.S:** An interesting question, I believe, is: *"Are there infinitely many $N^3$ (especially for prime $N$) that **cannot** be expressed as a sum of three positive cubes?"*

For example, there are no positive integers,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = 999959^3$$

even though the percentage of $N<1000000$ with solutions should be close to $99\text{%}$.

Comment: So what I said is correct but can the proof that all these

Comment: Perfect numbers can be infinitely expressed as sum of three cubes is it present or do I have to prove it

Comment: we find that the cube every perfect number can be expressed as sum of cubes in infinitely many ways not because its perfect but because as you say the odds are in favour but we cannot find a general proof that these cube of perfect numbers can be expressed as the sum of three cubes in infinitely many ways. So my question is still there because I want a general proof for thoa

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay: I said, _"...chances are it can be expressed as a sum of positive cubes in many ways as well."_ Where did you get the *infinitely* many part? Surely you see there can't be infinitely many positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is a constant sum? (And, yes, it is not a water-tight proof for perfect numbers. There might not any at all, since the sum of three positive cubes property is due more to statistics, rather than on its "perfectness".)

Comment: So there will be no proof at all

Comment: One can always be surprised.

Comment: Proof is there that means

Comment: If the proof is there can you give me any lead which I can follow in proving it

Comment: Can j post your question Tito piezas about large cubes which cannot be expressed as sum of three cubes if there is no proof for my question

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay: I was planning to ask that myself in MO, along with more details. Maybe you can have this question, and I can have that other one? :)

Comment: Thanks and I will find a proof for the perfect number question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20571/discussion-between-sayan-chattopadhyay-and-tito-piezas-iii).

Comment: This remarkably interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I played myself with this formula and proved that if the following ratio holds:

$$\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{abc} = 6$$

then the three integers:

$$x_1 = a + b$$
$$x_2 = a + c$$
$$x_3 = b + c$$

are such that: $$ x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 = y^3 $$

Proof is very simple:

Compute: $$ (a+b+c)^3$$

this gives: $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3[a^2(b+c) + b^2(a+c) + c^2(a+b)] + 6abc$$
now gather these addendums in three variables, forgetting about "6abc" for a while:

$$\alpha = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2$$
$$\beta = b^3 + 3b^2c + 3bc^2$$
$$\gamma = c^3 + 3c^2a + 3ca^2$$

now complete the gathering, adding to each variable a fraction of "6abc", obtaining:

$$x_1^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + k_1abc$$
$$x_2^3 = b^3 + 3b^2c + 3bc^2 + k_2abc$$
$$x_3^3 = c^3 + 3c^2a + 3ca^2 + k_3abc$$

these cubes are perfect if and only if:
$$k_1abc = b^3$$
$$k_2abc = c^3$$
$$k_3abc = a^3$$

with the additional condition: $$k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 6$$ where $$ k_1, k_2, k_3$$ are real
Now, the following equivalence holds:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=6abc$$

and so:

$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}=6$$

when this holds, the three numbers become:
$$x_1^3 = (a+b)^3$$
$$x_2^3 = (b+c)^3$$
$$x_3^3 = (c+a)^3$$

and then we have our sum of cubes.

Aftermaths!

This procedure does not say how to find the three numbers, but indeed once you find them, it is easy to show that each group of three base numbers, multiplied by an integer "h" still gives a sum of cubes that results in a perfect cube.
As an example, say:
(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
then:
$$x_1 = 1 + 2 = 3$$
$$x_2 = 2 + 3 = 5$$
$$x_3 = 3 + 1 = 4$$

but also:

$$(a, b, c) = h(1, 2, 3)$$ with $$h \in \mathbb R$$ is a solution. Proof is starightforward:

if $$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}=6$$ holds, then also

$$\frac{h^3a^3+h^3b^3+h^3c^3}{hahbhc}=6$$ does. In fact you can group $$h^3$$ both above and beneath and then simplify.

One last thing to mention. Of course, while this does not help us in finding the three base numbers, it tells us that, once found, the number a+b+c=n has a perfect cube. Moreover, each number m=hn, with $$h \in \mathbb N$$ is a perfect cube either.

That's it. I don't know where this has been proven, because this is only the result of my spare time calculations. I hope some of you might find it interesting enough to share opinions and ideas.
Now I'm trying the same for the more general rule:

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^n = y^n$$

but it already proved to be nasty!

Answer (score 2):

***This is more of a comment as opposed to an answer***

---

There is a formula for finding the values of $a, b, c, d$ in the following equation: $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3$$ Where $$\forall x, y\in \mathbb{Z}, \ \begin{align} a &= 3x^2 + 5y(x - y), \ b = 2\big(2x(x - y) + 3y^2\big) \\ c &= 5x(x - y) - 3y^2, \ d = 2\big(3x^2 - 2y(x + y)\big) \end{align}$$

Therefore if we prove this conjecture, we prove that every perfect number $d$ must be even! I also would like to expand this theorem as well with a theorem of mine:

> > If $$\forall\{x, y, z\}\subset \mathbb{N}, \ 6^3 + (2x)^3 + (2y - 1)^3 = z^3$$ Then $$z \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$$ Where $z$ is a prime number. If $z$ is not a prime number, then $z\equiv3\pmod 6$
>
> Examples: $$\begin{align} 6^3 + 8^3 + 1^3 &= 9^3 \qquad \ \ \ \ \mid9 &\equiv 3 \pmod 6 \\ 6^3 + 32^3 + 33^3 &= 41^3 \qquad \ \ \mid41 &\equiv 5 \pmod 6 \\ 6^3 + 180^3 + 127^3 &= 199^3 \qquad \mid199 &\equiv 1 \pmod 6 \\ 6^3 + 216^3 + 179^3 &= 251^3 \qquad \mid251 &\equiv 5 \pmod 6 \\ 6^3 + 718^3 + 479^3 &= 783^3 \qquad \mid783 &\equiv 3 \pmod 6 \\ 6^3 + 768^3 + 121^3 &= 769^3 \qquad \mid769 &\equiv 1 \pmod 6 \end{align}$$

Comment: How did you derive your formulae for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?  Were you able to prove that it is the *only such* formula, @MrPie?

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown that if $\sigma$ is an *even* perfect number then $\sigma^3$ can be expressed as a sum of three positive cubes.  Since there are no known odd perfect numbers, this also means that the cubes of all *known* perfect numbers can be so expressed. But it doesn't guarantee that every perfect number can be so expressed, since it hasn't been proved that there are no odd perfect numbers (although that seems very likely - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers)).

To prove the proposition for the even case, first note that (as pointed out in Thomas Andrews' comment) an even perfect number $\sigma$ must be of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where $p$ and $2^p-1$ are prime (see [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectNumber.html), equation (15) and following paragraph). Hence any $\sigma$ with $p>8$ has $2^8$ as a factor. But:

$$(2^8)^3=256^3=9^3+183^3+220^3$$

Hence for any such $\sigma$:

$$\sigma^3= (2^82^{p-9}(2^p-1))^3=(9(2^{p-9})(2^p-1))^3+(183(2^{p-9})(2^p-1))^3+(220(2^{p-9})(2^p-1))^3$$

It remains to show that the proposition holds when $p\leq8$. But the only such cases are $p=2,3,5,7$ yielding respectively $\sigma=6,28,496,8128$ which have already been  dealt with in the question and, for $8128$, in the answer by Tito Piezas III.