# Are there infinitely many $N^3$ (especially for prime $N$) that cannot be expressed as a sum of three positive cubes?"

Tags: number-theory

Well few days ago i [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/) on perfect numbers and  Tito Piezas III answered the question in a very intriguing way which has helped me to get a lead on it.But his answer and perfect numbers made us land on a very interesting question about cubes.

The sequence A023042 on the OEIS website shows that a large percentage of $N^3$ are a sum of three positive cubes. OEIS lists only N<1770, but we can extend that:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
N&\text{%}\\
2000&85.8\text{%}\\
4000&89.8\text{%}\\
6000&92.1\text{%}\\
8000&93.3\text{%}\\
10000&94.2\text{%}\\
\end{array}$$

This means that 94.2% of all N<10000 have a solution to $a^3+b^3+c^3=N^3$ in positive integers. Thus, if we pick a random N in the high end of that range, there is a very good chance that there is an a,b,c.

Now my question is that:Are there infinitely many $N^3$ (especially for prime $N$) that cannot be expressed as a sum of three positive cubes?

For example, there are no positive integers,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=999959^3$$

even though the percentage of N<1000000 with solutions should be close to 99%.

Please help me in this question or provide me with any lead.
The OEIS website link is: [oeis.org/A023042](https://oeis.org/A023042)

Comment: I'd get an approximate formula for the number f (N) of triples a ≤ b ≤ c with a^3 + b^3 + c^3 ≤ N^3, calculate f' (N) and see if that grows to infinity.

Comment: @Sayan: I fixed the table.

Comment: @gnasher729: Actually, it is $0<a<b<c$. It is known that $x^3+2y^3=z^3$ has no rational solution.

Comment: Thanks Tito :)  well i am getting some leads on the perfect numbers

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about prime $N,$ but otherwise yes: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html