# Statistics for $N$ in sum of cubes $a^3+b^3+c^3 = N^3$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, experimental-mathematics

> **Q:** What is the percentage of $n$ up to a bound $N$ such that,
>   $$a^3+b^3+c^3 = n^3\tag1$$
>   has a solution in ***positive*** integers?

The sequence [A023042](https://oeis.org/A023042) shows a *large* percentage. I have [extended](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/can-the-cube-of-every-perfect-number-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes) that to $N=10000$,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
N&\text{%}\\
\hline
2000&85.8\text{%}\\
4000&89.8\text{%}\\
6000&92.1\text{%}\\
8000&93.3\text{%}\\
10000&94.2\text{%}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

This means that $94\text{%}$ of all positive integers $N<10000$ has a solution to $(1)$.

How high does the percentage go? From the trends, can one assume that it may reach $97,98,\,\text{or}\;99\text{%}$ if we go up the *millions* to $N=1000000$?

Comment: Naively, one would expect "roughly" $N^3$ different possible sums less than $N^3$, since you can choose $0, 1, \ldots, N-1$ for each of the three variables. Of course this back-of-the-envelope calculation ignores the fact that some integers can be written as a sum in more than one way.

Comment: @user7530: Thanks. Also, if I may add, the reason for this question is that there two posts already ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491672/)) that singles out how perfect numbers are "special" in that their cubes can be expressed as sums of three positive cubes. But if given a relatively small bound it turns out that, say $99\,\text{%}$ of $N$ below that bound can be so expressed anyway, then it is not a property of its "perfectness" at all.

Comment: Worth noting that the percentage of integers within the range 8001-10000 for which there exist solutions is already 97.8% ($[(10000 * 0.942)-(8000 * 0.933)] / 2000$).

Comment: @AdamBailey: Yes, it would be nice if someone with the programming skills can update the table a little higher.

Comment: @RosieF: The focus on perfect numbers is by others, ***not*** mine. (In fact, I don't subscribe to this focus.) Kindly see the linked posts above by two different OPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on **Jarek Wroblewski**'s [database](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/eslp/tables.htm) of co-prime solutions of equation 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=n^3\tag{1}$$
(thanks to link from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/can-the-cube-of-every-perfect-number-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes/1119047#1119047)), statistics of numbers $n$ which cannot be written in the form $(1)$, is in the table:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
range: 1 - N & cnt(N) & \% \\
\hline
1 - 10 & 8 & 80\% \\
1 - 100 & 46 & 46\% \\
1 - 1000 & 191 & 19.10\% \\
1 - 10000 & 581 & 5.810\% \\
1 - 100000 & 1192 & 1.192\% \\
1 - 1000000 & 1867 & 0.186\% \\
\hline
\end{array}

Empirically the $cnt(N)$ from this table can be described by rough evaluation:
$$
cnt(N) \approx (2\cdot \log_{10}N)^3.
$$

Talking about such $k$-digital numbers, we have:

\begin{array}{|l|c|l|l|}
\hline
k\mbox{-}digital & range & cnt & \% \\
\hline
1\mbox{-}digital & 1 - 9 & 8 & 88.889\% \\
2\mbox{-}digital & 10 - 99 & 38 & 42.222\% \\
3\mbox{-}digital & 100 - 999 & 145 & 16.111\% \\
4\mbox{-}digital & 1000 - 9999 & 390 & 4.3333\% \\
5\mbox{-}digital & 10000 - 99999 & 611 & 0.6789\% \\
6\mbox{-}digital & 100000 - 999999 & 675 & 0.0750\% \\
\hline
\end{array}

List of $6$-digital such numbers which have  form $\overline{9*****}$:

$
907517,
909911,
913487,
914237,
918463,
922073,
923713,
926183,
929981,
938257,
944701,
946549,
960037,
961853,
968021,
969011,
981947,
984563,
989783,
991961,
992219,
996671,
997727,
998813,
999959.
$

Exhaustive list of these numbers which are $<1000000$:

```
1   
2   pr.
3   pr.
4   2^2
5   pr.
7   pr.
8   2^3
10  2 * 5
11  pr.
13  pr.
14  2 * 7
15  3 * 5
16  2^4
17  pr.
21  3 * 7
22  2 * 11
23  pr.
26  2 * 13
31  pr.
32  2^5
33  3 * 11
34  2 * 17
35  5 * 7
37  pr.
39  3 * 13
43  pr.
47  pr.
49  7^2
51  3 * 17
52  2^2 * 13
55  5 * 11
59  pr.
61  pr.
62  2 * 31
64  2^6
65  5 * 13
68  2^2 * 17
73  pr.
74  2 * 37
77  7 * 11
79  pr.
83  pr.
86  2 * 43
91  7 * 13
94  2 * 47
98  2 * 7^2
101 pr.
104 2^3 * 13
107 pr.
109 pr.
118 2 * 59
119 7 * 17
124 2^2 * 31
128 2^7
130 2 * 5 * 13
131 pr.
136 2^3 * 17
143 11 * 13
146 2 * 73
148 2^2 * 37
149 pr.
154 2 * 7 * 11
155 5 * 31
157 pr.
158 2 * 79
161 7 * 23
163 pr.
165 3 * 5 * 11
166 2 * 83
169 13^2
173 pr.
182 2 * 7 * 13
183 3 * 61
195 3 * 5 * 13
208 2^4 * 13
211 pr.
215 5 * 43
221 13 * 17
223 pr.
227 pr.
233 pr.
236 2^2 * 59
237 3 * 79
245 5 * 7^2
248 2^3 * 31
253 11 * 23
257 pr.
259 7 * 37
263 pr.
271 pr.
272 2^4 * 17
273 3 * 7 * 13
277 pr.
283 pr.
286 2 * 11 * 13
296 2^3 * 37
299 13 * 23
301 7 * 43
310 2 * 5 * 31
313 pr.
314 2 * 157
316 2^2 * 79
329 7 * 47
337 pr.
338 2 * 13^2
341 11 * 31
343 7^3
347 pr.
353 pr.
357 3 * 7 * 17
359 pr.
367 pr.
397 pr.
401 pr.
403 13 * 31
409 pr.
413 7 * 59
416 2^5 * 13
421 pr.
427 7 * 61
429 3 * 11 * 13
433 pr.
439 pr.
442 2 * 13 * 17
443 pr.
449 pr.
455 5 * 7 * 13
457 pr.
463 pr.
466 2 * 233
473 11 * 43
481 13 * 37
511 7 * 73
518 2 * 7 * 37
539 7^2 * 11
542 2 * 271
544 2^5 * 17
553 7 * 79
559 13 * 43
563 pr.
566 2 * 283
571 pr.
581 7 * 83
592 2^4 * 37
593 pr.
607 pr.
611 13 * 47
626 2 * 313
628 2^2 * 157
637 7^2 * 13
641 pr.
658 2 * 7 * 47
659 pr.
681 3 * 227
683 pr.
694 2 * 347
706 2 * 353
715 5 * 11 * 13
719 pr.
727 pr.
734 2 * 367
743 pr.
749 7 * 107
763 7 * 109
767 13 * 59
785 5 * 157
789 3 * 263
806 2 * 13 * 31
809 pr.
811 pr.
818 2 * 409
823 pr.
826 2 * 7 * 59
832 2^6 * 13
839 pr.
845 5 * 13^2
857 pr.
878 2 * 439
881 pr.
883 pr.
884 2^2 * 13 * 17
913 11 * 83
914 2 * 457
917 7 * 131
941 pr.
947 pr.
949 13 * 73
953 pr.
962 2 * 13 * 37
989 23 * 43
997 pr.
1001    7 * 11 * 13
1009    pr.
1021    pr.
1022    2 * 7 * 73
1027    13 * 79
1039    pr.
1055    5 * 211
1061    pr.
1078    2 * 7^2 * 11
1079    13 * 83
1081    23 * 47
1088    2^6 * 17
1091    pr.
1097    pr.
1106    2 * 7 * 79
1118    2 * 13 * 43
1127    7^2 * 23
1141    7 * 163
1147    31 * 37
1162    2 * 7 * 83
1163    pr.
1165    5 * 233
1171    pr.
1177    11 * 107
1183    7 * 13^2
1186    2 * 593
1201    pr.
1211    7 * 173
1213    pr.
1241    17 * 73
1252    2^2 * 313
1274    2 * 7^2 * 13
1277    pr.
1279    pr.
1283    pr.
1289    pr.
1315    5 * 263
1343    17 * 79
1357    23 * 59
1361    pr.
1366    2 * 683
1373    pr.
1381    pr.
1385    5 * 277
1389    3 * 463
1399    pr.
1411    17 * 83
1412    2^2 * 353
1417    13 * 109
1423    pr.
1438    2 * 719
1477    7 * 211
1483    pr.
1487    pr.
1499    pr.
1505    5 * 7 * 43
1531    pr.
1547    7 * 13 * 17
1561    7 * 223
1567    pr.
1570    2 * 5 * 157
1589    7 * 227
1597    pr.
1601    pr.
1627    pr.
1631    7 * 233
1637    pr.
1646    2 * 823
1659    3 * 7 * 79
1693    pr.
1699    pr.
1709    pr.
1717    17 * 101
1721    pr.
1727    11 * 157
1739    37 * 47
1762    2 * 881
1768    2^3 * 13 * 17
1771    7 * 11 * 23
1777    pr.
1813    7^2 * 37
1828    2^2 * 457
1835    5 * 367
1859    11 * 13^2
1891    31 * 61
1894    2 * 947
1897    7 * 271
1924    2^2 * 13 * 37
1933    pr.
1939    7 * 277
1994    2 * 997
1997    pr.
2002    2 * 7 * 11 * 13
2003    pr.
2005    5 * 401
2011    pr.
2015    5 * 13 * 31
2021    43 * 47
2039    pr.
2041    13 * 157
2054    2 * 13 * 79
2078    2 * 1039
2081    pr.
2093    7 * 13 * 23
2099    pr.
2107    7^2 * 43
2122    2 * 1061
2145    3 * 5 * 11 * 13
2158    2 * 13 * 83
2165    5 * 433
2183    37 * 59
2191    7 * 313
2197    13^3
2249    13 * 173
2251    pr.
2287    pr.
2294    2 * 31 * 37
2297    pr.
2303    7^2 * 47
2309    pr.
2315    5 * 463
2347    pr.
2351    pr.
2359    7 * 337
2366    2 * 7 * 13^2
2389    pr.
2429    7 * 347
2447    pr.
2471    7 * 353
2531    pr.
2551    pr.
2579    pr.
2633    pr.
2686    2 * 17 * 79
2707    pr.
2719    pr.
2729    pr.
2741    pr.
2743    13 * 211
2771    17 * 163
2798    2 * 1399
2801    pr.
2807    7 * 401
2819    pr.
2843    pr.
2846    2 * 1423
2859    3 * 953
2873    13^2 * 17
2876    2^2 * 719
2891    7^2 * 59
2899    13 * 223
2923    37 * 79
2927    pr.
2941    17 * 173
2947    7 * 421
2953    pr.
2965    5 * 593
2966    2 * 1483
2971    pr.
2989    7^2 * 61
3013    23 * 131
3029    13 * 233
3035    5 * 607
3062    2 * 1531
3079    pr.
3119    pr.
3131    31 * 101
3143    7 * 449
3185    5 * 7^2 * 13
3209    pr.
3221    pr.
3273    3 * 1091
3317    31 * 107
3319    pr.
3329    pr.
3341    13 * 257
3361    pr.
3367    7 * 13 * 37
3371    pr.
3386    2 * 1693
3419    13 * 263
3457    pr.
3478    2 * 37 * 47
3481    59^2
3523    13 * 271
3536    2^4 * 13 * 17
3554    2 * 1777
3559    pr.
3569    43 * 83
3581    pr.
3603    3 * 1201
3626    2 * 7^2 * 37
3631    pr.
3673    pr.
3679    13 * 283
3718    2 * 11 * 13^2
3737    37 * 101
3739    pr.
3749    23 * 163
3773    7^3 * 11
3779    pr.
3794    2 * 7 * 271
3803    pr.
3817    11 * 347
3848    2^3 * 13 * 37
3859    17 * 227
3871    7^2 * 79
3877    pr.
3887    13^2 * 23
3913    7 * 13 * 43
3929    pr.
3941    7 * 563
3943    pr.
3959    37 * 107
3988    2^2 * 997
3997    7 * 571
4022    2 * 2011
4027    pr.
4033    37 * 109
4037    11 * 367
4045    5 * 809
4069    13 * 313
4079    pr.
4108    2^2 * 13 * 79
4129    pr.
4133    pr.
4157    pr.
4198    2 * 2099
4211    pr.
4219    pr.
4243    pr.
4253    pr.
4277    7 * 13 * 47
4343    43 * 101
4366    2 * 37 * 59
4373    pr.
4394    2 * 13^3
4441    pr.
4451    pr.
4459    7^3 * 13
4502    2 * 2251
4549    pr.
4561    pr.
4583    pr.
4589    13 * 353
4591    pr.
4729    pr.
4751    pr.
4771    13 * 367
4811    17 * 283
4943    pr.
4999    pr.
5011    pr.
5029    47 * 107
5123    47 * 109
5127    3 * 1709
5147    pr.
5161    13 * 397
5189    pr.
5239    13^2 * 31
5243    7^2 * 107
5297    pr.
5317    13 * 409
5323    pr.
5341    7^2 * 109
5483    pr.
5501    pr.
5557    pr.
5563    pr.
5663    7 * 809
5677    7 * 811
5693    pr.
5701    pr.
5743    pr.
5759    13 * 443
5782    2 * 7^2 * 59
5809    37 * 157
5839    pr.
5897    pr.
5911    23 * 257
5915    5 * 7 * 13^2
5999    7 * 857
6031    37 * 163
6043    pr.
6053    pr.
6121    pr.
6167    7 * 881
6173    pr.
6241    79^2
6253    13^2 * 37
6323    pr.
6373    pr.
6407    43 * 149
6419    7^2 * 131
6442    2 * 3221
6509    23 * 283
6557    79 * 83
6629    7 * 947
6643    7 * 13 * 73
6671    7 * 953
6734    2 * 7 * 13 * 37
6761    pr.
6772    2^2 * 1693
6779    pr.
6827    pr.
6983    pr.
7009    43 * 163
7013    pr.
7046    2 * 13 * 271
7057    pr.
7063    7 * 1009
7072    2^5 * 13 * 17
7079    pr.
7109    pr.
7118    2 * 3559
7129    pr.
7189    7 * 13 * 79
7211    pr.
7309    pr.
7319    13 * 563
7358    2 * 13 * 283
7433    pr.
7451    pr.
7459    pr.
7463    17 * 439
7478    2 * 3739
7541    pr.
7553    7 * 13 * 83
7583    pr.
7633    17 * 449
7637    7 * 1091
7639    pr.
7655    5 * 1531
7679    7 * 1097
7696    2^4 * 13 * 37
7742    2 * 7^2 * 79
7751    23 * 337
7757    pr.
7858    2 * 3929
7889    7^3 * 23
7907    pr.
7943    13^2 * 47
7967    31 * 257
7987    7^2 * 163
8039    pr.
8111    pr.
8131    47 * 173
8173    11 * 743
8239    7 * 11 * 107
8258    2 * 4129
8273    pr.
8423    pr.
8438    2 * 4219
8465    5 * 1693
8477    7^2 * 173
8539    pr.
8573    pr.
8609    pr.
8621    37 * 233
8627    pr.
8647    pr.
8681    pr.
8687    7 * 17 * 73
8693    pr.
8732    2^2 * 37 * 59
8819    pr.
8879    13 * 683
8921    11 * 811
8951    pr.
8981    7 * 1283
9007    pr.
9023    7 * 1289
9041    pr.
9098    2 * 4549
9161    pr.
9223    23 * 401
9347    13 * 719
9397    pr.
9421    pr.
9509    37 * 257
9547    pr.
9563    73 * 131
9643    pr.
9781    pr.
9811    pr.
9871    pr.
9886    2 * 4943
9943    61 * 163
9949    pr.
9961    7 * 1423
10015   5 * 2003
10027   37 * 271
10079   pr.
10093   pr.
10249   37 * 277
10257   3 * 13 * 263
10267   pr.
10321   pr.
10391   pr.
10447   31 * 337
10478   2 * 13^2 * 31
10517   13 * 809
10543   13 * 811
10601   pr.
10634   2 * 13 * 409
10717   7 * 1531
10781   pr.
10853   pr.
10859   pr.
10889   pr.
10893   3 * 3631
10907   13 * 839
11114   2 * 5557
11141   13 * 857
11239   pr.
11279   pr.
11309   43 * 263
11389   7 * 1627
11402   2 * 5701
11411   pr.
11453   13 * 881
11618   2 * 37 * 157
11678   2 * 5839
11869   11 * 13 * 83
11945   5 * 2389
12101   pr.
12197   pr.
12211   pr.
12233   13 * 941
12235   5 * 2447
12239   pr.
12263   pr.
12281   pr.
12307   31 * 397
12311   13 * 947
12323   pr.
12346   2 * 6173
12367   83 * 149
12377   pr.
12397   7^2 * 11 * 23
12431   31 * 401
12506   2 * 13^2 * 37
12577   pr.
12601   pr.
12631   17 * 743
12671   pr.
12691   7^3 * 37
12757   pr.
12953   pr.
12961   13 * 997
13013   7 * 11 * 13^2
13114   2 * 79 * 83
13117   13 * 1009
13133   23 * 571
13217   pr.
13259   pr.
13273   13 * 1021
13283   37 * 359
13309   pr.
13327   pr.
13351   13^2 * 79
13367   pr.
13411   pr.
13459   43 * 313
13531   7 * 1933
13537   pr.
13573   7^2 * 277
13579   37 * 367
13667   79 * 173
13683   3 * 4561
13705   5 * 2741
13715   5 * 13 * 211
13759   pr.
13793   13 * 1061
13841   pr.
14029   pr.
14053   13 * 23 * 47
14143   pr.
14144   2^6 * 13 * 17
14147   7 * 43 * 47
14249   pr.
14251   pr.
14369   pr.
14378   2 * 7 * 13 * 79
14567   7 * 2081
14651   7^2 * 13 * 23
14689   37 * 397
14693   7 * 2099
14699   pr.
14749   7^3 * 43
14837   37 * 401
14911   13 * 31 * 37
15139   pr.
15337   7^2 * 313
15461   pr.
15467   pr.
15743   7 * 13 * 173
15923   pr.
16001   pr.
16121   7^3 * 47
16133   13 * 17 * 73
16187   pr.
16429   7 * 2347
16451   pr.
16457   7 * 2351
16513   7^2 * 337
16591   47 * 353
16627   13 * 1279
16679   13 * 1283
16729   pr.
16757   13 * 1289
17029   pr.
17041   pr.
17183   pr.
17203   pr.
17207   pr.
17243   43 * 401
17249   47 * 367
17297   7^2 * 353
17299   pr.
17357   17 * 1021
17359   pr.
17443   pr.
17459   13 * 17 * 79
17471   pr.
17473   101 * 173
17489   pr.
17581   pr.
17627   pr.
17641   13 * 23 * 59
17693   13 * 1361
17789   pr.
17849   13 * 1373
17953   13 * 1381
17971   pr.
18053   7 * 2579
18169   pr.
18251   pr.
18363   3 * 6121
18407   79 * 233
18443   pr.
18493   pr.
18499   13 * 1423
18797   pr.
18913   pr.
19013   pr.
19201   7 * 13 * 211
19213   pr.
19279   13 * 1483
19286   2 * 9643
19331   13 * 1487
19379   pr.
19583   pr.
19649   7^2 * 401
19697   pr.
19715   5 * 3943
19739   pr.
19801   pr.
19937   pr.
20183   pr.
20237   7^3 * 59
20293   7 * 13 * 223
20303   79 * 257
20323   pr.
20333   pr.
20489   7 * 2927
20549   pr.
20587   7 * 17 * 173
20593   pr.
20627   pr.
20719   pr.
20831   37 * 563
20923   7^3 * 61
21013   pr.
21089   pr.
21151   13 * 1627
21203   7 * 13 * 233
21281   13 * 1637
21347   pr.
21407   pr.
21409   79 * 271
21434   2 * 7 * 1531
21521   pr.
21739   pr.
21911   pr.
21937   pr.
21941   37 * 593
22087   13 * 1699
22277   pr.
22373   13 * 1721
22381   pr.
22387   61 * 367
22451   11 * 13 * 157
22541   pr.
22607   13 * 37 * 47
22721   pr.
22849   73 * 313
22906   2 * 13 * 881
23197   pr.
23369   pr.
23527   7 * 3361
23569   7^2 * 13 * 37
23597   7 * 3371
23633   pr.
23717   37 * 641
23741   pr.
24209   43 * 563
24239   pr.
24333   3 * 8111
24478   2 * 12239
24622   2 * 13 * 947
24649   157^2
24697   pr.
24767   pr.
24953   pr.
24995   5 * 4999
25117   pr.
25229   pr.
25269   3 * 8423
25271   37 * 683
25301   pr.
25309   pr.
25342   2 * 12671
25343   pr.
25391   pr.
25499   43 * 593
25847   pr.
25889   pr.
25901   59 * 439
25922   2 * 13 * 997
26026   2 * 7 * 11 * 13^2
26039   13 * 2003
26173   7 * 3739
26195   5 * 13^2 * 31
26273   13 * 43 * 47
26491   59 * 449
26621   7 * 3803
26683   pr.
26702   2 * 13^2 * 79
26717   pr.
26723   pr.
26822   2 * 13411
26853   3 * 8951
26891   pr.
26899   37 * 727
26917   11 * 2447
27023   61 * 443
27053   13 * 2081
27077   pr.
27097   7^3 * 79
27127   pr.
27149   17 * 1597
27209   7 * 13^2 * 23
27329   pr.
27337   pr.
27491   37 * 743
27563   43 * 641
27586   2 * 13 * 1061
27587   7^2 * 563
27601   7 * 3943
27773   pr.
27785   5 * 5557
27953   pr.
27997   pr.
28181   pr.
28315   5 * 7 * 809
28369   11 * 2579
28379   13 * 37 * 59
28483   7 * 13 * 313
28909   pr.
29171   31 * 941
29231   pr.
29237   13^2 * 173
29369   43 * 683
29477   7 * 4211
29611   pr.
29663   pr.
29759   pr.
29822   2 * 13 * 31 * 37
29837   pr.
30007   37 * 811
30017   13 * 2309
30341   pr.
30431   pr.
30493   pr.
31709   37 * 857
31793   pr.
31927   7 * 4561
32002   2 * 16001
32119   pr.
32123   7 * 13 * 353
32681   11 * 2971
32719   pr.
32839   pr.
32911   pr.
33113   pr.
33127   157 * 211
33353   pr.
33427   pr.
33458   2 * 16729
33589   pr.
33601   pr.
33667   131 * 257
33679   pr.
33821   31 * 1091
33911   pr.
34141   pr.
34421   pr.
34487   pr.
34543   pr.
34871   pr.
34877   pr.
34918   2 * 13 * 17 * 79
35039   37 * 947
35051   pr.
35077   7 * 5011
35149   pr.
35653   101 * 353
35659   13^2 * 211
35801   pr.
35861   7 * 47 * 109
35939   83 * 433
36493   pr.
36599   pr.
36637   pr.
36814   2 * 79 * 233
36959   13 * 2843
36986   2 * 18493
36998   2 * 13 * 1423
37349   13^3 * 17
37397   pr.
37421   23 * 1627
37447   pr.
37579   pr.
37687   13^2 * 223
37693   pr.
37969   43 * 883
37999   13 * 37 * 79
38219   pr.
38233   13 * 17 * 173
38237   pr.
38453   pr.
38821   pr.
38867   pr.
39229   pr.
39377   13^2 * 233
39587   31 * 1277
39641   7^2 * 809
40127   pr.
40201   7 * 5743
40349   157 * 257
40519   pr.
40646   2 * 20323
40973   pr.
41569   11 * 3779
41611   pr.
41717   13 * 3209
42371   7 * 6053
42409   pr.
42719   pr.
42979   pr.
43147   13 * 3319
43169   7^2 * 881
43321   pr.
43433   13^2 * 257
43687   7 * 79^2
43693   13 * 3361
43753   pr.
43759   pr.
43771   7 * 13^2 * 37
43783   pr.
43991   pr.
43997   pr.
44461   173 * 257
44491   pr.
44507   pr.
44533   pr.
44683   pr.
44777   pr.
44941   13 * 3457
45329   pr.
45389   pr.
45667   pr.
45799   13^2 * 271
45887   pr.
45943   pr.
46403   7^2 * 947
46483   23 * 43 * 47
46511   pr.
46633   pr.
46757   pr.
46957   pr.
47138   2 * 7^2 * 13 * 37
47221   pr.
47453   7 * 6779
47471   37 * 1283
47629   pr.
47749   13 * 3673
47827   13^2 * 283
47963   pr.
48109   pr.
48215   5 * 9643
48623   pr.
48649   pr.
48767   pr.
48809   pr.
49117   pr.
49813   109 * 457
50261   pr.
50401   13 * 3877
50423   pr.
50501   11 * 4591
50549   pr.
50602   2 * 25301
50923   pr.
51233   7 * 13 * 563
51259   13 * 3943
51335   5 * 10267
51347   pr.
51407   pr.
51427   pr.
51479   pr.
51643   43 * 1201
51713   pr.
51763   37 * 1399
51802   2 * 59 * 439
51844   2^2 * 13 * 997
52031   7 * 7433
52346   2 * 7 * 3739
52361   pr.
52973   pr.
53281   pr.
53299   pr.
53431   7 * 17 * 449
53441   pr.
53729   13 * 4133
53813   pr.
54091   pr.
54847   13 * 4219
56167   pr.
56179   pr.
56209   pr.
56281   23 * 2447
56393   pr.
56593   17 * 3329
56849   13 * 4373
57301   pr.
57671   101 * 571
57767   61 * 947
57863   13 * 4451
58109   pr.
58711   pr.
58979   pr.
59137   13 * 4549
59153   149 * 397
59203   73 * 811
59447   pr.
59651   pr.
59677   83 * 719
59771   pr.
60091   pr.
60107   pr.
60251   pr.
60427   pr.
61559   pr.
61657   pr.
61717   pr.
61879   pr.
62023   13^2 * 367
62071   pr.
62189   pr.
62341   31 * 2011
62477   pr.
62501   pr.
62657   7 * 8951
62753   pr.
63209   31 * 2039
63743   pr.
63773   pr.
64127   7 * 9161
64613   pr.
64747   pr.
64793   pr.
65063   pr.
65171   pr.
65678   2 * 32839
65687   pr.
65927   pr.
66499   pr.
66509   pr.
66599   13 * 47 * 109
66911   13 * 5147
67055   5 * 13411
67457   13 * 5189
68219   pr.
68281   pr.
68282   2 * 34141
68713   pr.
68813   pr.
68899   pr.
69121   13^2 * 409
69257   pr.
69539   pr.
69551   157 * 443
69809   pr.
69869   109 * 641
70189   7 * 37 * 271
70583   pr.
70651   7 * 10093
70709   pr.
70783   pr.
70937   pr.
71107   211 * 337
71279   13 * 5483
71537   pr.
71743   7 * 37 * 277
71821   pr.
72731   257 * 283
73019   pr.
73039   pr.
73079   pr.
73123   83 * 881
73849   pr.
74003   43 * 1721
74339   79 * 941
74453   pr.
74843   pr.
74887   pr.
75193   pr.
75209   pr.
75517   13 * 37 * 157
76013   7 * 10859
76469   47 * 1627
76661   13 * 5897
76667   pr.
77003   pr.
77339   pr.
77987   7 * 13 * 857
78121   pr.
79039   pr.
79337   pr.
79511   23 * 3457
79573   13 * 6121
79877   7 * 11411
79949   31 * 2579
80171   7 * 13 * 881
80527   pr.
81133   13 * 79^2
82757   pr.
83617   pr.
84737   pr.
84823   271 * 313
85037   pr.
85241   13 * 79 * 83
85871   43 * 1997
86177   7 * 13 * 947
86329   131 * 659
86639   7 * 12377
87181   pr.
87293   pr.
87506   2 * 43753
87542   2 * 7 * 13^2 * 37
87587   pr.
87677   43 * 2039
88241   pr.
88833   3 * 29611
89051   pr.
89561   pr.
91081   pr.
91169   13 * 7013
91741   13 * 7057
91819   7 * 13 * 1009
92467   pr.
92519   7 * 13217
92593   pr.
92677   13 * 7129
92857   pr.
93559   pr.
93859   47 * 1997
94879   79 * 1201
95063   pr.
95143   pr.
95191   pr.
95423   37 * 2579
95654   2 * 13^2 * 283
95663   271 * 353
95669   7 * 79 * 173
96119   277 * 347
96793   43 * 2251
97298   2 * 48649
97369   pr.
97813   pr.
97847   pr.
98123   pr.
98203   7 * 14029
98467   pr.
98627   pr.
98953   pr.
99307   13 * 7639
99431   pr.
99643   pr.
100159  37 * 2707
100469  pr.
100583  7 * 14369
100673  pr.
100813  73 * 1381
101063  pr.
101741  pr.
101969  7^2 * 2081
102061  pr.
102293  pr.
102481  pr.
102557  7^3 * 13 * 23
102893  7 * 14699
103135  5 * 20627
103393  pr.
103595  5 * 20719
103669  pr.
103681  pr.
103861  283 * 367
103979  pr.
104021  pr.
104087  pr.
104939  101 * 1039
105467  pr.
105943  pr.
105991  83 * 1277
106319  pr.
106739  pr.
106853  pr.
107549  13 * 8273
107963  107 * 1009
108182  2 * 54091
108289  pr.
108587  pr.
108767  23 * 4729
109831  pr.
109847  pr.
109859  pr.
110707  149 * 743
110753  pr.
111007  13 * 8539
111323  pr.
111431  pr.
111667  pr.
111917  13 * 8609
112237  pr.
112249  pr.
112601  pr.
112786  2 * 56393
112853  13 * 8681
112931  7 * 13 * 17 * 73
112967  pr.
113009  13 * 8693
113131  pr.
113383  pr.
113621  pr.
114113  pr.
114713  pr.
115003  7^2 * 2347
115021  pr.
115061  pr.
115601  pr.
115637  pr.
117422  2 * 58711
117463  101 * 1163
118033  pr.
118061  pr.
118757  pr.
118787  pr.
118967  pr.
120949  79 * 1531
121139  pr.
121557  3 * 40519
121679  271 * 449
122039  pr.
122231  pr.
122473  13 * 9421
123847  271 * 457
124067  pr.
124991  pr.
125353  pr.
125471  pr.
125659  pr.
126751  pr.
127241  pr.
128119  pr.
128323  13 * 9871
128551  pr.
128849  7 * 79 * 233
129493  7 * 13 * 1423
129509  pr.
130211  pr.
130351  13 * 37 * 271
130769  pr.
130927  pr.
131209  13 * 10093
131519  pr.
131843  31 * 4253
131959  pr.
132391  7 * 18913
132397  43 * 3079
132761  pr.
134177  pr.
134741  pr.
135257  pr.
135671  pr.
136483  pr.
136607  pr.
136663  17 * 8039
137081  7 * 19583
137849  pr.
138005  5 * 7 * 3943
138077  pr.
138283  pr.
138641  pr.
138889  pr.
139837  pr.
139861  pr.
140411  pr.
140537  313 * 449
140779  pr.
140951  59 * 2389
141709  pr.
142327  pr.
144779  pr.
145139  pr.
145259  pr.
145757  pr.
146627  13 * 11279
146921  pr.
147091  7 * 21013
149429  7 * 21347
149863  7 * 79 * 271
150041  pr.
150383  pr.
151157  pr.
152921  37 * 4133
153877  pr.
154493  pr.
154501  pr.
154613  pr.
154811  149 * 1039
154841  pr.
155783  pr.
156131  pr.
156227  pr.
156727  pr.
156817  pr.
157457  pr.
157679  pr.
158351  pr.
158497  353 * 449
158561  13 * 12197
158621  pr.
158743  13 * 12211
159107  13 * 12239
159419  13 * 12263
159421  pr.
159653  13 * 12281
160337  223 * 719
160423  pr.
162523  pr.
163019  pr.
163321  pr.
163529  43 * 3803
164291  pr.
164837  pr.
165001  pr.
165514  2 * 82757
166799  pr.
167429  pr.
167777  pr.
168293  pr.
169733  pr.
170531  31 * 5501
170647  pr.
171623  73 * 2351
171781  283 * 607
171821  13 * 13217
172199  pr.
173251  13 * 13327
173483  pr.
173671  pr.
174893  pr.
174973  37 * 4729
175159  107 * 1637
175229  pr.
176303  pr.
177007  pr.
177029  211 * 839
177883  pr.
178877  pr.
179309  13^2 * 1061
179933  13 * 13841
180331  pr.
181277  pr.
181997  pr.
182641  pr.
183847  157 * 1171
184199  pr.
184279  pr.
184963  37 * 4999
185437  7 * 59 * 449
186619  pr.
186797  13 * 14369
187027  pr.
188039  43 * 4373
188753  pr.
189371  7 * 13 * 2081
189539  7 * 27077
189851  pr.
190607  pr.
191063  17 * 11239
191087  13 * 14699
191509  pr.
193843  13^2 * 31 * 37
193883  pr.
197359  pr.
197767  pr.
198689  pr.
200579  pr.
200993  13 * 15461
201529  79 * 2551
201683  pr.
202121  pr.
202219  pr.
203257  439 * 463
204679  pr.
204751  pr.
204931  pr.
205531  47 * 4373
205763  pr.
206077  pr.
206177  pr.
206347  pr.
206477  pr.
206489  pr.
208667  pr.
208729  pr.
208877  pr.
210913  pr.
211213  pr.
212419  pr.
212767  263 * 809
213451  7 * 30493
213827  pr.
213863  13 * 16451
218081  pr.
218915  5 * 43783
218971  pr.
219953  pr.
221377  13 * 17029
221909  pr.
222029  pr.
222997  173 * 1289
223463  pr.
224027  pr.
224171  pr.
224861  7^2 * 13 * 353
224887  13 * 17299
225641  13 * 17 * 1021
225667  13 * 17359
226967  13^2 * 17 * 79
227147  pr.
227653  pr.
227693  pr.
228097  pr.
228359  pr.
230917  37 * 79^2
232559  313 * 743
232637  59 * 3943
232907  pr.
233951  37 * 6323
234809  pr.
234989  pr.
235007  pr.
235969  83 * 2843
237701  pr.
238331  pr.
240367  157 * 1531
240947  7 * 34421
241261  pr.
243847  59 * 4133
244139  7 * 34877
245257  pr.
245273  7 * 37 * 947
247343  pr.
249863  pr.
250259  pr.
251303  13^2 * 1487
251843  pr.
252911  pr.
253949  pr.
254291  pr.
255023  pr.
255167  11 * 23197
257707  pr.
258277  pr.
258407  pr.
258967  pr.
259099  pr.
259327  173 * 1499
262739  pr.
263611  pr.
263939  13 * 79 * 257
264139  pr.
265169  pr.
265483  pr.
265571  pr.
267143  pr.
267227  pr.
267709  13 * 20593
267913  pr.
268151  13 * 20627
268897  pr.
269921  47 * 5743
270514  2 * 135257
272069  7 * 38867
273169  13 * 21013
273289  pr.
273971  pr.
278317  13 * 79 * 271
279143  pr.
279773  13 * 21521
281783  pr.
283183  pr.
283511  pr.
285613  pr.
288007  pr.
288089  pr.
289381  pr.
290057  pr.
290471  pr.
292469  pr.
292549  pr.
295373  13 * 22721
297037  13 * 73 * 313
297727  pr.
298939  233 * 1283
302597  pr.
303247  7 * 43321
303869  277 * 1097
305851  7 * 13 * 3361
306377  pr.
307859  pr.
308573  pr.
309823  pr.
310081  pr.
310693  pr.
311407  pr.
311651  37 * 8423
312469  pr.
314711  pr.
316847  pr.
316861  pr.
318287  pr.
321313  pr.
321757  pr.
322319  pr.
322727  pr.
324559  59 * 5501
325471  271 * 1201
326521  13 * 25117
326941  pr.
327977  13 * 25229
328523  13 * 37 * 683
328913  13 * 25301
329471  pr.
330569  pr.
331213  pr.
331577  pr.
332887  pr.
333161  pr.
335029  pr.
335554  2 * 167777
336247  pr.
336353  pr.
336763  7 * 48109
338507  13^2 * 2003
338927  pr.
341333  pr.
341569  pr.
344653  pr.
344819  pr.
349927  pr.
352853  pr.
353411  pr.
356927  pr.
359627  107 * 3361
361033  pr.
361049  13 * 27773
363389  13 * 27953
363491  pr.
366461  pr.
368558  2 * 184279
368623  61 * 6043
368831  271 * 1361
369269  pr.
369487  pr.
373181  pr.
373441  37 * 10093
373669  pr.
374087  7 * 53441
374753  pr.
375997  pr.
376237  pr.
381214  2 * 190607
381797  13 * 43 * 683
382267  pr.
383627  pr.
385703  61 * 6323
385831  pr.
387799  pr.
388517  107 * 3631
388559  283 * 1373
389287  pr.
391753  pr.
392699  pr.
394249  pr.
398941  pr.
399433  pr.
399797  401 * 997
407177  pr.
409867  pr.
414629  pr.
415379  pr.
415741  31 * 13411
416639  401 * 1039
417557  7 * 59651
417691  pr.
418079  pr.
419609  pr.
420851  pr.
421757  7 * 60251
422029  pr.
423091  pr.
424129  pr.
425311  101 * 4211
426757  pr.
427513  pr.
428249  pr.
432737  pr.
433589  13 * 33353
435371  pr.
437011  pr.
439141  pr.
445331  223 * 1997
446129  pr.
450293  pr.
451433  107 * 4219
452701  pr.
453199  pr.
454823  pr.
457267  pr.
459523  pr.
467477  pr.
470039  pr.
471619  pr.
474127  pr.
474533  pr.
474823  457 * 1039
475469  pr.
476281  13 * 36637
478523  pr.
479189  pr.
480817  283 * 1699
482021  pr.
482051  pr.
483619  pr.
486161  13 * 37397
486341  pr.
486473  13 * 23 * 1627
486637  pr.
487727  pr.
489871  pr.
489931  13^3 * 223
490009  13 * 37693
492547  11 * 44777
493987  13^2 * 37 * 79
494771  61 * 8111
495481  7 * 70783
495619  pr.
496559  7 * 70937
496817  pr.
497081  13 * 38237
499487  367 * 1361
501569  83 * 6043
505051  pr.
505409  pr.
506213  pr.
506393  pr.
507797  pr.
507839  pr.
509879  pr.
509963  pr.
511591  pr.
512059  pr.
515093  149 * 3457
515611  pr.
517151  pr.
517217  pr.
517549  pr.
518207  pr.
519227  pr.
521399  pr.
522241  367 * 1423
524471  43 * 12197
527213  37 * 14249
529513  pr.
530303  pr.
531133  pr.
533543  pr.
534631  pr.
535849  pr.
543359  pr.
544139  pr.
544727  pr.
548201  pr.
554189  pr.
558727  13 * 42979
560233  pr.
560761  pr.
561197  7^2 * 13 * 881
566101  pr.
567751  pr.
567767  pr.
571031  pr.
571799  pr.
578929  13 * 44533
589261  79 * 7459
589277  13 * 45329
590057  13 * 45389
592307  pr.
596569  pr.
600109  pr.
601207  pr.
602873  pr.
603239  7^2 * 13 * 947
604643  13 * 46511
604861  pr.
608411  pr.
608989  pr.
609101  pr.
610429  pr.
617123  13 * 37 * 1283
619177  13 * 47629
623437  pr.
625253  pr.
625697  pr.
634517  13 * 48809
636071  pr.
636761  pr.
637409  pr.
638347  pr.
638801  pr.
639077  641 * 997
641747  pr.
645397  pr.
651251  pr.
655213  13^2 * 3877
655499  13 * 50423
655507  pr.
657826  2 * 13 * 25301
658871  pr.
659279  pr.
659759  pr.
660661  pr.
662063  pr.
662407  pr.
667663  449 * 1487
679741  pr.
684419  pr.
690793  pr.
691079  pr.
692887  13 * 53299
696671  173 * 4027
696809  pr.
698477  13^2 * 4133
701279  pr.
702077  pr.
713129  pr.
722521  pr.
722963  pr.
723161  pr.
729551  pr.
730717  13 * 56209
732217  pr.
732763  43 * 17041
733823  pr.
735101  367 * 2003
738313  pr.
739943  pr.
744913  13 * 57301
747223  pr.
752219  13^2 * 4451
752321  37 * 20333
757543  pr.
758707  pr.
760109  7 * 108587
763243  13 * 58711
765971  pr.
770111  pr.
771973  pr.
773023  pr.
777191  pr.
778201  pr.
778933  pr.
782849  pr.
788231  pr.
790331  pr.
792059  37 * 21407
794011  pr.
797347  79 * 10093
800447  pr.
803483  pr.
808457  13 * 62189
809231  pr.
810409  pr.
811273  pr.
811879  pr.
812057  pr.
819911  pr.
819989  pr.
820481  pr.
820837  pr.
823129  pr.
823619  pr.
824671  pr.
828659  13 * 63743
832757  pr.
839551  pr.
839969  13 * 64613
841711  13 * 64747
842309  13 * 64793
845371  pr.
845879  pr.
851821  pr.
860077  pr.
860513  pr.
860623  pr.
862061  pr.
863179  pr.
865511  pr.
875981  pr.
880939  pr.
887653  13 * 68281
893269  13 * 68713
895787  pr.
896479  pr.
897593  pr.
907517  13 * 69809
909911  pr.
913487  pr.
914237  pr.
918463  7 * 13 * 10093
922073  pr.
923713  7 * 131959
926183  pr.
929981  13 * 71537
938257  pr.
944701  pr.
946549  pr.
960037  13 * 73849
961853  pr.
968021  pr.
969011  pr.
981947  pr.
984563  pr.
989783  pr.
991961  pr.
992219  pr.
996671  13 * 76667
997727  pr.
998813  pr.
999959  pr.
```

Note: $1007$ of them are prime numbers.

And here is table which shows how many numbers of the list above are divisible by $p,p^2,p^3$ for first unsolvable primes $p$:

\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p & \mbox{divisible  by } p & ...\; p^2 & ...\;p^3 \\
\hline
2 & \color{blue}{177} &  41 & 22\\
3 & 31 &-&-\\
5 & \color{blue}{53} &-&-\\
7 & \color{blue}{218} & 52 & 11 \\
11 & 43 &-&-\\
13 & \color{blue}{300} & 46 & 4 \\
17 & 47 &-&-\\
23 & 31 &-&-\\
31 & 34 &-&-\\
37 & \color{blue}{82} &-&-\\
43 & 39 &-&-\\
47 & 29 &-&-\\
59 & 24 &1&-\\
61 & 13 &-&-\\
73 & 16 &-&-\\
79 & 48 &4&-\\
\hline
\end{array}

There are also $15$ $n$ div by $2^4$. (Hmm, note that factors $7$, $13$ occur often enough).

Comment: Beautiful! So for $N<1000000$, then $99.8\text{%}$ can be expressed as $a^3+b^3+c^3 = N^3$ How did you data-mine Jarek's table? (I used Mathematica and Excel which was a primitive way and got overflow for large ranges of $N$.)

Comment: By the way, of the $25$ integers in your last paragraph, $19$ are prime, or more than $75\%$.

Comment: Noting that the 25 integers in your last paragraph are all odd, is it possible to identify the largest even $n < 1000000$ which cannot be written in the form (1)?

Comment: @AdamBailey: From Jarek's tables, it seems $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 999998^3$ has no solution. But Jarek used ***co-prime*** $a,b,c$. If we removed the co-primality condition, then we have $$7874^3(13^3+ 65^3+ 121^3) =  999998^3$$ among others. Oleg took this into account in his table above and his list of $1867$ unsolvable $n$ should start as $n= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14,\dots$ and should have a largest even member.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, I created array of the size $1000000$, 
made its cells "empty"; and for each $(n;a,b,c)$ from the database marked array's cells $n, 2n, 3n, ... $ as "filled" ($\approx$ like Sieve of Eratosthenes).
After this routine,
if the cell is "empty", then $n^3$ cannot be written as the sum of $3$ positive cubes.

Comment: @AdamBailey, I'll update answer with these numbers soon; the largest even $n<1000000$ of this list is $657826$ (few largest even numbers of this list: $270514, 335554, 368558, 381214, 657826$).

Comment: What software did you use? Can't be Excel like what I did.

Comment: @Tito, I used C++ language; maybe Mathematica or Excel can be used too.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: As was pointed out by OP, a lot of unsolvable composites were factorable by $2,7,13$. It turns out unsolvable powers are $2,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5,2^6,2^7$ and $7,7^2,7^3$ and $13,13^2,13^3$. Hmm.

Comment: Oleg: Favor, I'm going blind data-mining your table by hand. Can you modify your summary to include how many of the composites are divisible by $p^2$ for $p=2,3,5,7,11,13$. A quick look seems it is only for $p=2,7,13$.

Comment: @Tito: yes, sure. a few minutes.

Comment: There are few single squares: $59^2$, $79^2$, $157^2$, and $7\cdot 79^2$, $13\cdot 79^2$, $37\cdot 79^2$.

Comment: @Oleg567: Thanks. I also extended your table. Hm, what is so special about the primes $2,5,7,13,37,79$ with reference to cubes?

Comment: I've asked that question in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286020/what-is-so-special-about-a3b3c3-13m3).

Comment: @Oleg567: For your single squares, we have $6*13+1 = 79$ and $12*13+1 = 157$. May be just coincidence though.