# Find whole numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3=a^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find whole numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3=a^3$

I have got no solution till now.

Please also provide a formula for finding solutions for this equation.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Why did you tag this question ‘linear algebra’?

Comment: Formula how to find solutions

Comment: Why would you expect this to be straight forward?  In general, the sum of three cubes problem is extremely difficult.

Comment: Fully answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/can-the-cube-of-every-perfect-number-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the cube of every perfect number be written as the sum of three cubes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118456/can-the-cube-of-every-perfect-number-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes)

Answer (score 5):

Ramanujan gave the integer solutions
$$
\begin{align*}
x & = 3n^2 + 5nm - 5m^2 \\
y & = 4n^2 - 4nm + 6m^2 \\
z & = 5n^2 - 5nm - 3m^2 \\
w & = 6n^2 - 4nm + 4m^2 
\end{align*}
$$

for $x^3+y^3+z^3=w^3$. The smallest one is
$$
3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3.
$$