# Can a cube be divided into three cubes?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are distinct integers.
Is
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$$
possible?

Comment: $ (9t^3 + 1)^3 + (9t^4)^3 + (-9t^4 - 3t)^3 = 1$, for example.

Comment: See e.g. [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010), section 2.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469151/find-all-integer-solutions-to-diophantine-equation-x3y3z3-w3/776918#776918

Answer (score 0):

There exist infinitely many solutions $(a,b,c,d), a,b,c,d \in Z$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3$. specifically, just consider the 4-tuples of the form $(a,0,0,a)$. Note that the they trivially satisfy the equation. Hence proved.

Comment: Are there any solutions where a, b, c, and d are not 0?

Comment: @Someone I strongly suggest you amend your question something like this: > **EDIT:** Although I did not say so at first, I intend the choice of integers to be such that $abcd \neq 0$.

Comment: However, as I think more about this, Lelouch, your answer nevertheless fails to answer Someone's question as originally written, since "distinct integers" means $a \neq d$.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, though, now I see that @MyGlasses's edit actually changes the meaning of the original question. Jeez!

Comment: Yeah, the previous question was trivially true. Thats all i posted here.