# Cube of a positive integer is equivalent to 3 other positive integers cubed

Tags: polynomials

How could we determine if there exists an integer d such as

$$     d^{3} =  a^{3}  + b^{3} + c^{3} $$

I don't need to find a,b,c. I just need to know if a solution exists for a given d.
I know for example that for $a=3$, $b=4$, $c=5$ and $d=6$ the equation holds.

Thank you

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413031/how-many-cubes-are-the-sum-of-three-positive-cubes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all integer solutions to Diophantine equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=w^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469151/find-all-integer-solutions-to-diophantine-equation-x3y3z3-w3)

Comment: $3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = \color{red}{\text{what ?}}$

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-28/issue-4/On-Equal-Sums-of-Cubes/10.1216/rmjm/1181071714.full This paper should suffice for a complete solution.

Comment: @Hersh is the pdf file of this article freely available for download, somewhere on the internet?

Comment: @user2661923 Just click on the "Download paper" Button that should be on your screen. It is free.