# Solving Cubic Systems of Diophantine Equations

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, cubics

What techniques are there for solving systems of Cubic Diophantine equations? I know there is no general purpose technique and looking at some papers it can quickly go over my head even for just a single equation. Any good resources for someone who has not worked with such equations very often and the foundations? When looking I mainly find papers which are not great for learning from or seems like a lot the other beginner resources mainly cover linear Diophantine systems which I can deal with via linear algebra, and also not what I am looking for since I am dealing with cubics.

For example I can brute force the following with a computer program I quickly wrote:

$$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  z^3 = w^3 + x^3 - y^3 \\
&  z^3 = w^3 + u^3 - v^3
\end{aligned}\right. $$

One such solution I get is:

$$ \left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  9^3 = 16^3 + 33^3 - 34^3\\
&  9^3 = 16^3 + 2^3 - 15^3 
\end{aligned}\right. $$

The problem is if I start to have more variables and more equations to the system brute force becomes infeasible quickly. So some better methods to attack the problem to know if even a solutions exists and even find them would be great.

Also I notice when looking at just an equation in isolation a lot times I can find someone who has already found a parametrization of a given equation out the various systems I am messing with. I have tried combining 2 or more parametrizations, but this also seems quite hard.

For example the equations I gave as example above, I have found a paramizations for $ a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 $ which both equations in the example are a form of. Since the example is a set of simultaneous equations with repeated variables means I can I set parts of the parametrization equal to each other, but this just causes the number of variables to explode if the system has lots more equations and often again falls back to brute force unless I can rewrite the parametrization in the same variables as the other one. However, when I try this I often end up with an equation that no long gives integer solutions mainly because I end up with having cuberoots/squareroots and such. So it would seems like this method would not work.

So I guess back to my first paragraph, I am just mainly looking for information/resource and techniques for working with such systems. Ideally with the goal parametrization of the system or determining if a solution exists.

--Edited--
Individ asked for an example to work on. I guess we can use the example posted above to see what techniques one may use to maybe solve such a system. Solutions exists since I found some via brute force so at least so a parametric solution should exist I think?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [Thue Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)

Comment: Hardy and Wright give a complete  rational parametrization, 13.7.8, page 200 in the fifth edition. They also give a  parametrization for some of the integral solutions by Ramanujan.

Comment: That was just an example of the kinds equations I am playing with. Some are much larger systems with more equations. Generally, 4 to 6 equations with 9 to 12 variables. I assume the book your talking about it is: An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers I will try and take a look. However, to solve a system it seems like I need other tools than just a parametrization of each equation as I explained above unless I am missing something.

Comment: . W. Tanner, I looked at that Wikipedia article it only seems to apply to a function of 2 variables. For example let say I had the just this system consisting 2 equations a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3 + e^3 + f^3 and e^3 + f^3 = a^3 + w^3.

Comment: Difficult. Very difficult. I do not know anyone else besides me who is currently engaged in nonlinear systems of diophantine equations. Some systems I have solved. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046t281f3046_system_of_equations

Comment: The problem, for example, in your equation is that two equations of the 3rd degree. This means that it is necessary to solve an algebraic equation of at least the 6th degree. And we know that this cannot be done. The only way out is to deceive nature and apply the methodology of holistic algebra. There formulas can be extremely cumbersome. But the problem is not limited to this. The method of holistic algebra is categorically unacceptable. They are struggling with them. You ask such a question - an answer that will be categorically unacceptable.

Comment: Edit the question. Choose one equation and let's try to solve it. There is no guarantee that it will work, but you can try.

Comment: "Difficult. Very difficult." That's what it seems like when messing around. I guess we could try the example I gave above. I know a solution exists since I found multiple by brute force. It would be interesting to see what techniques there are to try and attack such a problem.  Also what do you mean by "holistic algebra"?

Comment: There is one idea how to solve such a system. To do this, it is worth asking one more additional question first. First, solve the problem of 4 cubes. Ask this question. But it is not just necessary to find a solution. It is known. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_четырёх_кубах  And find such a parametrization so that it describes all solutions and they have a maximum of 2 degree of parameter.  And then it will be enough to solve a system of equations of 2 degrees. Ask this question, and then we'll see what we can do next.

Comment: The main method to try binary cubic forms is working in cubic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ and this is a difficult topic. And you ask about more unknowns.

Comment: $n = a^2 + 2b^2 + 3c^2 + 4d^2 + 5e^2 + ⋯$, which can be expressed as "How many ways can a given integer n be written as the sum of a square plus twice a square plus thrice a square and so on?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this task so difficult? Formally, it is necessary to solve such a system of equations.

$$A^3+B^3=C^3+Q^3=R^3+F^3$$

It is impossible to solve such a system of equations directly. Firstly, there are few variables for a power of 3. The more variables, the easier it is to solve. Secondly, a direct solution leads to an algebraic equation of degree 9. That is, the formula cannot be written.

Therefore, we will need some kind of trick to deceive nature. And the idea here is simple. In fact, we are dealing with the problem of 4 cubes. If we have parametrization, then it will be enough for us to solve a system of 2 diophantine equations in which $A,B -$ are expressed in 2 sets of different parameters.

And then I decided to use the well-known parametrization formulas for the 4-cube problem. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_четырёх_кубах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85)

I can write to a large extent myself. Only in the solution it will not help.

[Find all integer solutions to Diophantine equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=w^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469151/find-all-integer-solutions-to-diophantine-equation-x3y3z3-w3/776918#776918)

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1872888_five_dice

And then I was disappointed. Parameterization is usually of the 3rd degree and higher.

Instead of one complex system, it will be necessary to solve another even more complex system. I'm a lazy person, so I thought and decided that I needed to find some simple parametrization. The second degree is best. From three variables.

Because quadratic parametrization from 2 variables does not give all solutions. That's where the problem arose. Quadratic parametrization is possible if we solve a quadratic equation. That is, the equation of the 3rd degree must somehow be converted into a square. And I can solve the quadratic equation well.

As soon as this chain of conclusions and the direction of decisions became clear. Everything else turned out to be very simple. And in the equation...

$$A^3+B^3=C^3+Q^3$$

You can write such a parametrization.

$$A=28a^2+12ab-68ac+2b^2-16bc+42c^2$$

$$B=21a^2+ab-43ac-b^2+bc+21c^2$$

$$C=42a^2+16ab-100ac+2b^2-20bc+60c^2$$

$$Q=-35a^2-15ab+85ac-b^2+17bc-51c^2$$

Well, then you will need to solve a system of quadratic diophantine equations.I'll write about it later....  So far, I have solved the problem of 4 cubes.

P.S. - I would like to say a few words about the formula. When I wrote it for 4 cubes. I decided to use it to solve the system in finding coefficients. And there a rather funny pattern turned out. Which naturally did not allow to solve this system. Maybe someone will have ideas how to get around it?

If we take and set any numbers - as parameters --- $a,b,c$

And if we substitute new coefficients in the formula instead of the old ones - as a single number added to them.

$a \Longrightarrow p+a $

$b \Longrightarrow p+b $

$c  \Longrightarrow p+c $

Then the same numbers will always be obtained...  $-- A,B,C,Q$ It's so funny.

Note 2....

It turned out that parameterization of such a form can be made up a lot. For example, this. Which can save us from the symmetry of the formula. But so far it has been possible to obtain a formula with large coefficients...

$$A^3+B^3=C^3+Q^3$$

$$A=1144a^2-2024ab-11176ac+900b^2+9896bc+27300c^2$$

$$B=-559a^2+989ab+5461ac-435b^2-4826bc-13335c^2$$

$$C=273a^2-547ab-2731ac+269b^2+2726bc+6825c^2$$

$$Q=1092a^2-1928ab-10664ac+856b^2+9424bc+26040c^2$$

If there are other formulas, then we must try to find one that is not symmetric and with small coefficients.

Square parameters are reduced to two anyway.

$$A=k(3(k^3-2t^3)(k^2+kt+t^2)x^2+3(k+t)(k^3-2t^3)xy+(k+t)(k^2-t^2)y^2)$$

$$B=t(k+t)(3(k^4+k^2t^2+t^4)x^2+3t^3xy+(t^2-k^2)y^2)$$

$$C=k(k+t)(3(k^4+k^2t^2+t^4)x^2+3k^3xy+(k^2-t^2)y^2)$$

$$Q=t(-3(2k^3-t^3)(k^2+kt+t^2)x^2-3(k+t)(2k^3-t^3)xy+(k+t)(t^2-k^2)y^2)$$

Further, to solve it, it is necessary to solve a system of nonlinear equations.

Another approach of the solution - led anyway to two quadratic parameters.

$$A=(3k-t)((81k^5-108k^4t+63k^3t^2-27k^2t^3+6kt^4-t^5)x^2+3(9k^3-9k^2t+3kt^2-t^3)xy+(3k-2t)y^2)$$

$$B=t(3k(27k^4-36k^3t+21k^2t^2-6kt^3+t^4)x^2+t^3xy-(3k-2t)y^2)$$

$$C=(3k-t)(3k(27k^4-36k^3t+21k^2t^2-6kt^3+t^4)x^2+(3k-t)^3xy+(3k-2t)y^2)$$

$$Q=t((-162k^5+216k^4t-126k^3t^2+45k^2t^3-9kt^4+t^5)x^2-3(18k^3-18k^2t+6kt^2-t^3)xy-(3k-2t)y^2)$$

Comment: Interesting, when you say "parameterization of such a form can be made up a lot", I was trying to see for example how you got those coefficients.Can you expand on that a little further? For example in the first parameterization all the a^2 coefficients can be divided by 7, and in the second all can be divided by 13.

Comment: It turns out there is a formula - which is more cumbersome. And there is probably some dependence there. I think it's worth writing down this formula and then it will be seen why this is so.

Comment: What was the other approach you used for that second set of equations? I appreciate the explanation and what work you have put in thus far. Although I think I probably need to study more on this topic to better deal with what I am messing with other than bruteforce. Any books you recommend?

Comment: There are no recommendations. I found the formulas myself. You need to formalize another question where it will be necessary to consider the solution of a system of two quadratic diophantine equations in a general form. I think the question should be formalized separately.