# Algebraic relations between alternative representations of an integer in the form $p^2+3q^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

In the course of pondering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776322/sums-of-three-cubes-of-form-a3b3c3-c13?noredirect=1&lq=1) I noticed that $4[(c+1)^3 – c^3]$ can be represented in the form $p^2 + 3q^2$ in *three* different ways:

$$4[(c+1)^3 – c^3] = 12c^2 + 12c + 4$$

$$= 1^2 + 3(2c+1)^2$$

$$= (3c+1)^2 + 3(c+1)^2$$

$$= (3c+2)^2 + 3c^2$$

This property also holds for some other integers not of the above form, for example:

$$52 = 7^2 + 3(1^2)$$

$$= 5^2 + 3(3^2)$$

$$= 2^2 + 3(4^2)$$

Other small integers with this property are $124$ and $172$.  In each case the three representations are related by the identity:

$$p^2 + 3q^2$$

$$= \bigg(\dfrac{p+3q}{2}\bigg)^2 + 3\bigg(\dfrac{p-q}{2}\bigg)^2$$

$$= \bigg(\dfrac{p-3q}{2}\bigg)^2 + 3\bigg(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\bigg)^2\qquad(1)$$

This yields integers whenever $p$ and $q$ are both odd or both even.  If any one representation is known, the other two can be readily calculated.

There are also integers which can be represented in the form $p^2+3q^2$ in *six* different ways, including $364$, $532$ and $868$.  In each case the six ways can be divided into two groups of three, each exemplifying identity (1).  For example:

$$364 = 19^2 + 3(1^2)$$

$$= 11^2 + 3(9^2)$$

$$= 8^2 + 3(10^2)$$

$$364 = 17^2 + 3(5^2)$$

$$= 16^2 + 3(6^2)$$

$$= 1^2 + 3(11^2)$$

*Question*:  For integers representable in the form $p^2+3q^2$ in two groups of three ways, each group an instance of identity (1), is there any algebraic relation between the two groups (which would enable all the other five to be calculated if any one were known)?

Comment: This form is a norm of a ring. So perhaps studying (factoring in) that ring helps ?

Comment: There will be three ways for any $4p,$  where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  is prime. Write the prime as $p=u^2 + 3 v^2.$ This gives $4p=(2u)^2 + 3 (2v)^2$  with the other two coming from Gauss composition and $4 = 1 + 3.$  You get more for composite; note $364 =4 \cdot 7 \cdot 13,$  $532 =4 \cdot 7 \cdot 19,$  $868 =4 \cdot 7 \cdot 31,$   add in   $988 =4 \cdot 13 \cdot 19,$   see chpter one in Cox  http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf

Comment: $ (u^2 + 3 v^2)(x^2 + 3 y^2) = (ux+3vy)^2 + 3 (uy-vx)^2 =   (ux-3vy)^2 + 3 (uy+vx)^2 $

Comment: Thanks to an insight from this post, I figured out the answer to a new question of mine. Kindly see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845639/what-is-the-relation-between-these-pairs-of-triangles-on-an-ellipse-for-x3y3).

Comment: @Adam I added more detail to my answer about how $p^2+3q^2 = 364$ and the others can be used to find solutions to $a^3+b^3+c^3 = (c+m)^3$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

(*A partial answer. A complete answer would be relevant to [a recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845639/what-is-the-relation-between-these-pairs-of-triangles-on-an-ellipse-for-x3y3) of mine.*)

**I. Sum of cubes**

Bailey mentioned he noticed $4\big((c+1)^3 – c^3\big)$ can be represented in the form $N = p^2 + 3q^2$ in three ways. That came from considering the equation,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (c+m)^3$$

for $m=1$. However, if we allow *rational* $m$, then all the examples he gave can be used in such an equation. To illustrate,

Let $p^2+3q^2 = 364,$ and $r=\dfrac{34p+30q+17}{30}+11$ then,

$$\left(p+q+48\right)^3+\left(p-q+\tfrac{11}2\right)^3+r^3 = \left(r+\tfrac{75}2\right)^3$$

Let $p^2+3q^2 = 532,$ and $r=\dfrac{4p+3q+2}{3}+22$ then,

$$\left(p+q+42\right)^3+\left(p-q+10\right)^3+r^3 = \left(r+24\right)^3$$

Let $p^2+3q^2 = 868,$ and $r=\dfrac{11p+3q+2}{3}+106$ then,

$$\left(p+q+35\right)^3+\left(p-q+24\right)^3+r^3 = \left(r+3\right)^3$$

and similarly for $N = 52, 124, 172.$ But not all $N$ will do. The general procedure is discussed in [this second post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847666/on-the-elliptic-curve-x3-6-cdot-1632-x-7-cdot-1633-y2-and-others) and involves an elliptic curve.

---

**II. Ellipses**

Given an integer $N = p^2+3q^2$ expressible in three ways,

$$N = x_1^2+3y_1^2 =  x_2^2+3y_2^2  = x_3^2+3y_3^2$$

it may be useful to let the $(x_k,y_k)$ be *signed*. So the given identity becomes,

$$N = (-p)^2+3(-q)^2 = \left(\frac{p+3q}2\right)^2+3\left(\frac{-p+q}2\right)^2 = \left(\frac{p-3q}2\right)^2+3\left(\frac{p+q}2\right)^2$$

such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 0.$ These three $(x_k,y_k)$ will be the vertices of a *triangle*.

Assume the ellipse $p^2+3q^2-364=0.$ Starting with initial solution $(p,q) = (19,1)$ and using the identity above, we find three vertices. And the other initial solution $(p,q) = (17,5)$ will give three more vertices.

[image]

The blue dots give the first triangle, while the green dots give the second triangle. If instead we consider the six points as the vertices of a *hexagon*, then we have [Pascal's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTheorem.html),

$\hskip1.1in$[image]

where the three pairs of the continuations of opposite sides meet on a straight line. So there is a relationship between the two triangles. But the question is if we can derive the second from the first.

In [the first post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845639/what-is-the-relation-between-these-pairs-of-triangles-on-an-ellipse-for-x3y3) I cited, I was able to derive from one triangle (blue vertices) another triangle (green vertices), resulting in a pair of distinct polynomial sextuplets that solve $x^3+y^3+z^3 = (z+1)^3$. For example, $594^3 + 1003^3 + 20154^3 = 20155^3.$

[image]

However, as pointed out by Eric Towers, one way to see the derivation was an appropriate *rotation* of the first triangle since connecting all six antipodes intersect at the center. But whether there is an appropriate rotation/transformation for Bailey’s two triangles remains to be seen.

Comment: Maybe related? Cremona, Luigi. Teoremi stereometrici dai quali si deducono le proprietà dell'esagrammo di Pascal,1877.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks! Googling that work by Cremona led me to Pascal's Theorem which I added to my answer.

Comment: The comment did go to the more mysterious pascal hexagram from the cubic surface, but in ellipse1 for the $n$-s I checked, it's a special case of pascal's theorem that shows up: The opposite sides are parallel!